# How to load the following sulu snippet in the twig.html file

Tags: twig, sulu

I have created the following social media snippet with sulu (headless cms) and now I want to use it in my twig.html file. The only problem is that I don't understand which variables I use to get it running. I have tried a variety of different ways but I just don't understand what variables I need to use so that I can link the social media links correctly. Thanks in advance for the help.

I use sulu as headless cms, and symfony/twig to render it.

This is the Sulu code I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<template xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template http://schemas.sulu.io/template/template-1.0.xsd">

<key>socialmedia</key>

<meta>
    <title lang="en">Social Media</title>
    <title lang="de">Social Media</title>
</meta>

<properties>
    <property name="title" type="text_line" mandatory="true">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Title</title>
            <title lang="de">Titel</title>
        </meta>
        <tag name="sulu.node.name"/>
    </property>

    <property name="facebookImage" colspan="3" type="single_media_selection">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Facebook Icon</title>
            <title lang="de">Facebook Icon</title>
        </meta>
    </property>

    <property name="facebookLink" colspan="9" type="url">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Facebook Link</title>
            <title lang="de">Facebook Link</title>
        </meta>
        <params>
            <param name="schemes" type="collection">
                <param name="http://"/>
                <param name="https://"/>
            </param>
        </params>
    </property>

    <property name="instagramImage" colspan="3" type="single_media_selection">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Instagram Icon</title>
            <title lang="de">Instagram Icon</title>
        </meta>
    </property>

    <property name="instagramLink" colspan="9" type="url">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Instagram Link</title>
            <title lang="de">Instagram Link</title>
        </meta>
        <params>
            <param name="schemes" type="collection">
                <param name="http://"/>
                <param name="https://"/>
            </param>
        </params>
    </property>

    <property name="googleImage" colspan="3" type="single_media_selection">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Google Icon</title>
            <title lang="de">Google Icon</title>
        </meta>
    </property>

    <property name="googleLink" colspan="9" type="url">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Google Link</title>
            <title lang="de">Google Link</title>
        </meta>
        <params>
            <param name="schemes" type="collection">
                <param name="http://"/>
                <param name="https://"/>
            </param>
        </params>
    </property>
</properties>
```

Comment: @DarkBee It is an existing Project and there are already other files + also snippets. I don't really understand your comment but I think it already gets parsed. What would be the correct way to call the facebookLink in Twig if it gets parsed correctly?

Comment: read the content of xml file and you can use "simplexml_load_string" to return it as an object and then pass it ot twig  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: @hous - Nope, thats what I thought, but Sulu actually uses XML files to pass variables to the template

Comment: @hous That's not how it works with sulu as DarkBee said

Comment: Ah, sorry then...

Answer (score 1):

So you can create in your page a `snippet_selection` or `single_snippet_selection` to embed a snippet into your page.

If you want to create a snippet which is "global". You can create a [snippet area / default snippet](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.5/cookbook/default-snippets.html).

This means you add a area to your snippet:

```xml
<areas>
    <area key="settings">
        <meta>
            <title lang="en">Settings</title>
        </meta>
    </area>
</areas>
```

Then you go into the Sulu Admin and create a new snippet. After that you go to your Webspace and select unter "Default Snippets" under the point "Settings" the new snippet.

In your twig you can then load that snippet via the [`sulu_snippet_load_by_area.html`](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.5/reference/twig-extensions/functions/sulu_snippet_load_by_area.html) twig function:

```
{% set snippet = sulu_snippet_load_by_area('settings') %}

{% if snippet %} {# if null content manager did not choice a default snippet in "Default Snippets" Tabs on Webspace #}
   {{ dump(snippet) }} {# dump all properties #}
{% endif %}
```

PS: Try not to create a default/global snippet for every little things. Mostly it is for the "Content Manager" more usable to create 1 "Settings" snippet. Which you have a Section "Social Links" in it instead of having different default snippets.

Comment: How would OP access the different URL's defined inside the XML/snippet? (Just curious)

Comment: already tried that and implement in twig with `<img src="{{ snippet.content.facebookImage }}">` but it doesn't work

Comment: There shows up a `Impossible to access an attribute ("content") on a null variable.` Error and when I put an If Statement `{% if social_media.content is defined %}` there is nothing shown on the website

Comment: Sounds more like you did not yet select a snippet in the Sulu Admin if you get "null" on it. So Important you need to go to Your Webpace -> Default Snippets -> Your Area Name and Select a Snippet.
Else you will get NULL and you don't have a snippet loaded. You can always use {{ dump(yourvariable) }} to check the value of the loaded snippet.